# dns problem in samba addc

Tags: networking, server, samba, dns

```
auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet static  
address 192.168.1.254
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
network 192.168.1.0  
broadcast 192.168.1.255
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.1.254
dns-search aslami.com
```

If I put `8.8.8.8` in first, I have `ping google.com` but I don't have `ping to my local server aslami.com` or `server.aslami.com`.

But if I put `192.168.1.254` in first, I have `ping in my local server aslami.com` or `server.aslami.com`. When I `ping google.com`, in this case, it says `unknown host`.

Why both do not work at the same time?

Comment: How is the DNS server configured?

Comment: Should BOTH auto AND static be there? Remove auto. Did you do a `sudo ifdown eth0 ; sudo ifup eth0` after editing the DNS server changes?

Answer (score 0):

They do not work because the second server is only queried if the query of the first one returns with an error. An error is something like a timeout, an answer from the DNS server that the address/name is not know is not an error but a valid DNS answer.

Since you already have a DNS server in your network at *192.168.1.254* you should configure that one to use *8.8.8.8* as upstream server, so that your local DNS server can forward the DNS queries that are out of the local scope.
On your clients, just use *192.168.1.254* as DNS server and you are done.

To find the DNS server that is running at *192.168.1.254*, you could run the command as follows.

```
lsof -n -i:53
```

Now identify the DNS server binary and lookup the manpage to configure the upstream server.

Comment: can you help me to configure it?

Comment: A first step would be to find out which DNS server you are running at *192.168.1.254*. The output of `lsof -n -i:53` should reveal that. Best would be to add that to your question.

Comment: COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
samba   1857 root   39u  IPv6  23517      0t0  TCP *:domain (LISTEN)
samba   1857 root   41u  IPv6  23518      0t0  UDP *:domain 
samba   1857 root   42u  IPv4  23519      0t0  TCP *:domain (LISTEN)
samba   1857 root   43u  IPv4  23520      0t0  UDP *:domain

Comment: samba   1857 root   39u  IPv6  23517      0t0  TCP *:domain (LISTEN)